# how can i make summary transaction from dictionary?

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary

i have code like that:

```
bought = {'Banana':2, 'Avocado':3, 'Cherries':1}
price_of = {'Apple': 6,
'Avocado': 5,
'Banana': 3,
'Blackberries': 10,
'Blueberries': 12,
'Cherries': 7,
'Pineapple': 7}

bought = sorted(bought) 
def print_summary(items,fprice):
   items = bought
   for item, n in fprice.items():
      print(n, item, ':', n * items[item])
      print('total', sum(n * items[item])

print_summary(bought,price_of)
```

but i get output like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Pbv.png)

i want to make the output is like that:

```
3 Avocado : 15
2 Banana : 6
1 Cherries : 7
total : 28
```

Comment: what is `counter_item` and `chart`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it a bit messy, but works

```
bought = {'Banana':2, 'Avocado':3, 'Cherries':1}
price_of = {'Apple': 6,
'Avocado': 5,
'Banana': 3,
'Blackberries': 10,
'Blueberries': 12,
'Cherries': 7,
'Pineapple': 7}

#Creating a new sorted dictionary named b
a = sorted(bought)
b = {}
for fruit in a:
    b[fruit] = bought.get(fruit)
#Making bought be b
bought = b

def summary(items, price):
    total = 0
    for i in items:
        print(f" {items.get(i)} {i} : {items.get(i)*price.get(i)}")
        total = total + items.get(i)*price.get(i)
    print(f" Total {total}")

summary(bought, price_of)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
for fruit, quantity in sorted(bought.items()):
    print(f"{quantity} {fruit} : {quantity * price_of[fruit]}")
print(f"total : {sum(quantity * price_of[fruit] for fruit, quantity in bought.items())}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bought = {'Banana':2, 'Avocado':3, 'Cherries':1}
price_of = {'Apple': 6,
'Avocado': 5,
'Banana': 3,
'Blackberries': 10,
'Blueberries': 12,
'Cherries': 7,
'Pineapple': 7}

# bought = sorted(bought)
def print_summary(items,fprice):
#    items = counter_item(chart)
#    for item, n in fprice.items():
#       print(n, item, ':', n * items[item])
#       print('total', sum(n * items[item]))
    total = 0
    for i, k in enumerate(sorted(items, key= lambda x: items[x], reverse=True )):
        print(items[k], k, ':', items[k] * fprice[k])
        total += items[k] * fprice[k]
    print("total : {}".format(total))

print_summary (bought,price_of)
```

```
3 Avocado : 15
2 Banana : 6
1 Cherries : 7
total : 28
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You want to sort your dictionary in reverse order according to key value so you have to add that in your code. Here main concern is sorting so i have done multiplication of values in simple way.

```
bought = {'Banana':2, 'Avocado':3, 'Cherries':1}
price_of = {'Apple': 6,
'Avocado': 5,
'Banana': 3,
'Blackberries': 10,
'Blueberries': 12,
'Cherries': 7,
'Pineapple': 7}

bought['Banana'] *= price_of['Banana']
bought['Avocado'] *= price_of['Avocado']
bought['Cherries'] *= price_of['Cherries']

lst = list()
for k,v in bought.items():
    newtup = (v,k)
    lst.append(newtup)

lst = sorted(lst, reverse = True)
n=3
total = 0
for k,v in lst:
    print(n,' ',v,' : ',k)
    total = total + k
    n = n-1
print('total :', total)
```

output of this code is :

```
3   Avocado  :  15
2   Cherries  :  7
1   Banana  :  6
total : 28
```